# How to make button inline?

Tags: css, button, inline

I have two button, one have single line text and another have two line text. The buttons are not inline. How can i make it inline?

I try to fix it using different css style.

**Similar to this:**

```css
button{
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<button>Single Line</button>
<button>Multiline<br>Line</button>
```

Comment: Please include your [mcve] code in your question, don't (just) link to it hosted elsewhere.

Comment: please add your code here.

Comment: <div class="mainContainer">
            <button class="actionBtn btnVideo">Take a Video</button>
            <button class="actionBtn btnEvent">Attend Event<br><span>(Check-In/Check-Out)</span></button></div>

Comment: Don't post your code in the comments; edit your question, add your code and format it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `vertical-align:middle;`

```css
button{
  height:50px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
 <div class="mainContainer">
        <button class="actionBtn btnVideo">Take a Video</button>
        <button class="actionBtn btnEvent">Attend Event<br><span>(Check-In/Check-Out)</span></button>
    </div>
```

```css
button{
  height:50px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<button>Single Line</button>
<button>Multiline<br>Line</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The left button `.btnVideo` is `top: 8px;` written in the `/* top: 8px */` comments and not executed.
You can easily check that using inspect element if using google chrome.

Comment: It works for chrome using top:8px but not works in firefox.